# ¿Error 405: el verbo HTTP usado para obtener acceso a esta página no está permitido.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis, https, cors

Estoy desarrollando  una WEB API  e hice pruebas sobre el equipo y los verbos funcionan correctamente pero cuando lo subo a servidor remoto y ejecuto el los métodos PUT y DELETE, me aparece

> Error 405: el verbo HTTP usado para obtener acceso a esta página no está permitido.

Cambie el CORS para que admita todo pero nada funciona y no se que error tengo.

Comment: Puede ser la misma aplicación que estás usando, la cual al manejar las peticiones bloquea las que sean del tipo `PUT` o `DELETE`. Yo tengo una así en PHP, con un código escrito por mí que acepta solamente las peticiones del tipo `GET` y del tipo `POST`, y para las otras peticiones, me lanza una excepción. O puede ser un [bug](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/216493/bug-you-may-receive-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error-message-when)

Comment: Cuando ejecuto desde  Visual Studio funciona perfectamente pero cuando lo monto a servidor remoto, solo me deja GET y POST. Ademas, en la aplicación, puse que se permitiera cualquier método pero no meda

Comment: Quizás te ayude editando tu `web.config` y quitando `WebDAV`. Puedes guiarte de: [“405 method not allowed” in IIS7.5 for “PUT” method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147181/405-method-not-allowed-in-iis7-5-for-put-method#14976941)

Comment: Si ya con me dio te lo agradezco mucho. La pregunta es por que se debe remover el WebDAV ?

Comment: Si estás trabajando con IIS, yo tuve el mismo problema y lo pude solucionar con ésto: https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1358/405-method-not-allowed-error-with-put-or-delete-request-on-asp_net-application.aspx